# Class Expression Constructor

Tags: javascript, class, ecmascript-6, es6-class

With ES6, JavaScript has proper class syntax, allowing you to declare them either as `class A {}` or `const A = class {}`. The latter are class expressions.

I'm working on a project where everything is customizable. The user will create a new file with the same name except with a prefix, and anything in their file with overwrite that of the original. However, it seems as though you cannot do this with the constructor of a class expression.

```
const A = class {};
A.constructor = function(name) {
    this.name = name;
}
```

You would expect the above to work, (or even `A.prototype.constructor`) but it doesn't.

How does one properly define a constructor in this manner? I can't have it within the class declaration.

Comment: What does "but it doesn't" mean? What doesn't work? An error? Unexpected behavior?

Comment: @Carcigenicate What I mean is that nothing happens. `(new A('Name')).name` returns undefined, when it should return `'Name'`.

Comment: What do you mean by "*anything in their file with overwrite that of the original*"? What is the problem? What do you want the customisation to do? Why can't you have it within the class declaration (hint: you'll need to)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`class` syntax creates a constructor function and fills in the object assigned to its `prototype` property. There isn't a "class" separate from the constructor function. In your example, `A` is a reference to the constructor function created by the `class {}` expression. While you can replace the value of the `constructor` property on the object assigned to `A.prototype`, that won't change what function `A` refers to, and so won't change what happens via `new A`.

You can set `A.prototype.constructor`, and then give `class A` a `constructor` that defers to the one defined on the prototype **if** it's not the same function anymore, forwarding any arguments that were passed. That creates markedly unusual classes (normally, `A.prototype.constructor === A` is `true`), but does what you need it to do.

```js
const A = class {
  constructor(...args) {
     let Constructor = A.prototype.constructor
     if (Constructor !== A) {
       Constructor.apply(this, args);
     }
  }
};

(A.prototype.constructor = function(name) {
    this.name = name;
}).prototype = A

console.log(
  new A('It works!')
)
```

**Edit:** Another option, which avoids messing with `A.prototype.constructor`, would be to have a static `Constructor` property defined on `A` that you can change to your liking:

```js
const A = class {

  static Constructor = Function.prototype
  
  constructor(...args) {
     A.Constructor.apply(this, args);
  }
};

A.Constructor = function(name) {
    this.name = name;
}

console.log(
  new A('It works!')
)
```

Comment: Could you explain why, briefly? I'm curious as to why this strategy doesn't play nicely with class inheritance (and it might help OP later on, too).

Comment: I don't have any super or subclasses in my entire codebase so that won't be a problem at all. And this will do the trick nicely. Thank you.

Comment: @Spedwards: Cool, then the above is easily your best bet.

Comment: @gyre: There's no need to use `A.prototype.constructor.apply(this, args);`, just use `this.constructor(...args);` I've also added a bit more explanation and added a check to prevent endless recursion.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, and good catch concerning the endless recursion... always good to learn something new.

Comment: Actually I think this works just fine with sub- and super-classing except when subclassing something that expects `constructor` to be the real constructor (like `Promise`).

Comment: You'll also want to copy over the `prototype` property, e.g.: `A.prototype.constructor = function() { /*...*/}; A.prototype.constructor.prototype = A.prototype;` in case something uses `constructor` rather than `A` (like `Promise` does in `then`), for cases where you're not subclassing.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Accessing the `.constructor` explicitly and using `apply` is advised when you want to work with inheritance

Comment: Don't ever overwrite `.constructor`! This "works", but is a **horrible hack**. Please don't use this in production.

Comment: @Bergi Of course we know this, but the premise of OP's question involves changing a class's `constructor` after it has been created. If you can think of a more elegant way to do this that avoids the property, please share it with us!

Comment: @Bergi: I know, that's why I called it out above.